# for await (... of ...) not working. Babel present env, node v10

Tags: node.js, async-await, babeljs, babel-node

It's been a while since I started a nodejs project from scratch, so was a bit of a headscratcher to set up and configure eslint, babel etc.

right now my babelrc is :

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`package.json` has dev dependencies:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
```

Now I want to loop over a list of objects. For each, I need to perform some asynchronous tasks that I'll need to `await` on, so I did:

```js
for await (const thing of things) {
  const foo = await doSomethingThatTakesAwhile(thing)
  // etc
}
```

but when I run it in dev (nodemon via babel-node) now there's a syntax error on the await:

```
for await (const thing of things) {
    ^
Syntax Error Unexpected token, expected (
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (... \node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (... \node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (... \node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1749:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseForStatement (... \node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2008:8)
etc..
```

Do I have to change my babel config, and/or have I completely misunderstood *for/await* and *await/async* ?

Comment: can you show us what command `node -v` print out?

Comment: @jfriend00 thx for the comment. It wont be at the top level, it will actually be inside an async func; this was just for demonstration it is not my exact code. Eventually, `things` will also become an async, so I knew i would have to use for-await-of regardless. My main issue was getting it to compile and that is solved. Will come to grips with syntax and fitness for purpose a bit later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another project in which i know `for await of` works... it looks like I'm using old babel plugins and not the new, separated out `@babel/xxx` libs. After trial and error installing and uninstalling stuff: this is the resulting babelrc that worked:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      },
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  ]
}
```

By this point I had installed all of:

- @babel/core
- @babel/node
- @babel/cli
- @babel/preset-env
- @babel/plugin-transform-runtime

Then I ran into this issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10128
So Had to also install @babel/runtime pegged at 7.0.0-beta.55 ... and now it builds!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the [babel-plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions#installation) plugin to use the for await of syntax.

Comment: trying that out now... will report back! :)

Comment: Yikes. The only other one I can think of is [transform-async-generator-functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions)